# How to load kernel modules in initramfs

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, initrd

I have a block device module that has to be loaded **before** the file system.
I'm told that I have include the module into an `initramfs` and boot from it.

Then I've created my own `initramfs` width dracut, put my `.ko` file into `/user/lib`, I've also generated new `grub.cfg`.

However, after reboot, `lsmod` shows that the `.ko` file is not loaded.

So I'd like to know what should I do make the module loaded automatically when I reboot?

Thank you.

P.S. I'm using Centos 7.

Comment: Centos 7 is using systemd, right? I think it possible to create a configuration *.conf file in /etc/modules-load.d/ and specificy the module name inside it. This at least makes sure that the module is loaded at boot, but I don't know if is also loaded earlier then automatically probed modules.

Comment: Yes it's using Systemd, thank you for your reply. @MauriceLaveaux

Comment: I don't know exactly what dracut does different from mkinitcpio, but I have tested it myself using the latter and it works, so I could try to explain the steps in that one if you want.